# How can I access a variable in $scope from inside a filter function?

Tags: angularjs

I need to alter how a filter works based on a setting in my controller. Can I access controller vars from my filter? Do I add the var on to the filter parameter list in the template?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass whatever you need from your controller into the filter function. e.g.:

JS

```
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function(input, myParam) {
        if (myParam) {
            return input;
        } else {
          return [];
        }
    };
}
```

HTML

```
<div>{{myCtrl.someList | myFilter:myCtrl.someSetting}}</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the handle bars in your HTML be double? For example, {{something}}

Comment: @KanwarG yep. Edited it

Answer (score 1):

If you are invoking the filter in the view, you can add the var in the filter parameter list.
Any vars appended to the filter parameter list in the view, will be appended to the filter function arguments (after the filtered object).
E.g.:

The filter:

```
.filter('doSomeFiltering', function () {
    return function (someObj, myVar1, myVar2) {
        ...
    };
});
```

The view:

```
{{thisWillBeSomeObj | doSomeFiltering:thisWillBeMyVar1:thisWillBeMyVar2}}
```

The controller:

```
$scope.thisWillBeSomeObj = ...;
$scope.thisWillBeMyVar1 = ...;
$scope.thisWillBeMyVar2 = ...;
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Ee9A6/)**.